# Define an empty Dict where the values are the subtype of an abstract type

Tags: dictionary, julia, abstract-data-type

I've got an abstract type, with subtypes.
I'd like to make and add to a Dict that holds the subtypes.
Is this doable?
What's a better way of achieving this?

Example:

```
abstract type Cat end

struct Lion <: Cat
   manecolour
end

struct Tiger <: Cat
   stripewidth
end

cats = Dict{Int, <:Cat}()
```

gives

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Dict{Int64,var"#s3"} where var"#s3"<:Cat()
```

What's the more correct way of doing this?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62972989/659248

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the abstract type as the container type: `cats = Dict{Int, Cat}()`:

```
julia> cats = Dict{Int, Cat}()
Dict{Int64,Cat}()

julia> cats[1] = Lion(12)
Lion(12)

julia> cats
Dict{Int64,Cat} with 1 entry:
  1 => Lion(12)
```

Answer (score 1):

Types are of the type `DataType` - except `UnionAll`s. So you could do

```
julia> d = Dict{Int, Union{DataType, UnionAll}}()
 Dict{Int64,Union{DataType, UnionAll}}()

julia> for (i, type) in enumerate(subtypes(Integer))
           d[i] = type
       end

julia> d
 Dict{Int64,Union{DataType, UnionAll}} with 3 entries:
  2 => Signed
  3 => Unsigned
  1 => Bool
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number of `Cat` types is small you can avoid using abstract container to boost the performance:

```
cats = Dict{Int, Cat}()
cats[1] = Lion(12)

cats2 = Dict{Int, Union{subtypes(Cat)...}}()
cats2[1] = Lion(12)
```

Now testing (I am using `Tiger` and `Lion` cat types):

```
julia> @btime $cats[1].manecolour == 12;
  25.300 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime $cats2[1].manecolour == 12;
  17.434 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```